# php - isset button

Tags: php, isset

i try to solve a problem but didnt succeed. I retrieve datas from google analytics and i have to send start and end date. I have two textbox and user select start and end date.However, but before user select [image]start and end date. The problem occurs..

The place that i use isset is here,

This is my full html

```
<?php
define('ga_email','mertmetinbjk@gmail.com');
define('ga_password','************');
define('ga_profile_id','*******');

require 'gapi.class.php';
require 'connectDB.php';

$ga = new gapi(ga_email,ga_password);




?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>İçerik</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="datetimepicker.js">

//Date Time Picker script- by TengYong Ng of http://www.rainforestnet.com
//Script featured on JavaScript Kit (http://www.javascriptkit.com)
//For this script, visit http://www.javascriptkit.com 

</script>
</head>
<div></div>
<body>
    <table align="center">
        <tr> 
        <td><br />
    <br />
    <form action="#" method="post" name="formDates" id="form1" >
    <table width="303" height="40" border="0" align="center">
        <table width =""
  <tr>
    <td>Başlangıç Tarihi</td>
    <td>
      <label for="txtStartDate"></label>
      <input type="text" name="txtStartDate" id="txt1" value="" /><a href="javascript:NewCal('txt1','ddmmyyyy')"><img src="images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Başlangıç Tarihi Seçin">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bitiş Tarihi</td>
    <td>
      <label for="txtEndDate"></label>
      <input type="text" name="txtEndDate" id="txt2" /><a href="javascript:NewCal('txt2','ddmmyyyy')"><img src="images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Bitiş Tarihi Seçin">
      </a>

    </td>
  </tr> 
    </form>
        <tr>
             <td><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Gönder"</td>
        </tr>

</table>
    <table width="1250" height="26" align="center">
  <tr>

    <td width="138"><strong>Kanal Adı</strong>
    <td width="150"><b>Kategori Adı</b></td>
    <td width="130"><p><strong>Event Adı</strong></td>
    <td width="145"><strong>Toplam</strong>

  </tr>
    </table>



            <?php

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){     
                $startDate = $_POST['txtStartDate'];
                $endDate = $_POST['txtEndDate'];  
             }


             $arrDates = explode("-",$startDate);
             $startDate=$arrDates[2]."-".$arrDates[1]."-".$arrDates[0];
             $arrDates = explode("-",$endDate);
             $endDate = $arrDates[2]."-".$arrDates[1]."-".$arrDates[0];

             echo $startDate;
             echo $endDate;



            $ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id,array('eventCategory','eventAction'),array('totalEvents'),$sort_metric=null,$filter='eventAction==InitPlayer',$start_date='2012-02-02',$end_date='2012-02-16');
            foreach($ga->getResults() as $result2);
            {
                echo $result2->geteventCategory();
                echo $result2->geteventAction();
                echo $result2->gettotalEvents();
            }


            $ga->requestAccountData();
            $mysql = new mysql(); 
            $mysql->connect();  
            $counter = 0;



            foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
            {     
                 echo $result . ' (' . $result->getProfileId() . ")<br />";
                 echo "<br />";
                 $counter++;
            }

            $result = mysql_query("select profile_id from profiles");
            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);



            if($counter != $num_rows)
            {
                $mysql->query("delete from profiles");

                foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
                { 
                   $mysql->query("insert into profiles values(".$result->getProfileId().",'".$result."')");
                }
            }






            ?>

</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

what is wrong?

if a choose start and end date problems is solved , problems occurs before that i choose

Comment: Post the html form. why not test if $_POST['txtStartDate'] is set? Make sure to react accordingly if txtStartDate and textEndDate are not set by either sending back an error message or throwing an exception.

Comment: Are you sure in your html form, the input elements have a `name` attribute? Its hard to help without the HTML code, but that's my shot in the dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

instead of:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
```

The exclamation mark in front of `isset` means `not`. Also I would check for the actual fields you want to use, not for `$_POST['submit']`:

```
if(isset($_POST['txtStartDate']) && isset($_POST['txtEndDate']))
{
    // Do something with $_POST['txtStartDate'] and $_POST['txtEndDate']
}
```

The reason you were getting the error is that `$_POST['submit']` does not exist. There is not `input` element with a `name` attribute called `submit`. Beware of the difference between `type` and `name`.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['txtStartDate']) && isset($_POST['txtEndDate']))
           {
             $startDate = $_POST['txtStartDate'];
             $endDate = $_POST['txtEndDate'];
             echo $startDate;
             echo $endDate;
             
            
           }
             This works thank you !!

Answer (score 3):

It must be `isset($_POST["btnSubmit"])` NOT submit

submit = type
btnSubmit = name of the button

Comment: you are absolutely right isset($_POST["submit"]) will not work because he used "btnSubmit" and not submit

Answer (score 1):

```
Undefined index txtStartDate, ...
```

It seems that your form may not be conforming to the same variable name specification with the one that you use in this php file. Make sure field names are matching within the form and here.

And also you should make these checks in your php file after submission success: `if(!isset($_POST['submit']))`

Answer (score 1):

When your page is loading and `$_POST['submit']` is not set, your `$_POST['txtStartDate']` and `$_POST['txtEndDate']` are not set so `$arrDates` is not set too. You need to check if these $_POST vars are set or not, to work with them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `isset()` on every variable, not just one variable. `$_POST['txtStartDate']` and `$_POST['txtEndDate']` and other variables are simply not defined, this means that they were not sent with the `POST` request.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
```

This means that if the **submit** button was **NOT** pressed. You should check if the `$_POST['submit']` is set, as a result of the form submission, like so:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` instead of `if(!isset($_POST['submit']))` as `!` in the start means a **negation**

Comment: @MertMETİN Are you sure you are performing a post request? Please show your html.